# Why does the array have more elements than I've defined?

Tags: c#, arrays

So, I've got this function which reads from an INI file:

```
private void GetRigInfo()
{
    RigInfo = new string[9];
    var fileLocation = new string[2];

    // The problem is that there's no telling where the hddrigsite.ini will be 
    stored.  So, we have to find out where it is from the hddconfig.ini.
    Log("Locating rig info");

    // There's no telling if this will be on a 32 or 64 bit OS.  Check for both
    var rigInfoLocation = File.ReadAllLines(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ?
                          @"C:\Program Files (x86)\HDD DrillView\hddconfig.ini" : 
                          @"C:\Program Files\HDD DrillView\hddconfig.ini");

    // This should get us the location of the rigsite info we need.
    foreach (var s in rigInfoLocation.Where(s => s.Contains("data_dir")))
    {
        fileLocation = s.Split('=');
    }

    RigInfo = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\\hddrigsite.ini");

    Log("Rig info found");
}
```

Now, when I step through, and get to the last `Log()` in the function, and I hover over `RigInfo`, Visual Studio intellisense shows me `RigInfo{string[30]}`.  Now, I've always understood that `= new string[9]` would create a 9 element array.  So why is it allowed to have 30 elements?  When I run the program, I get no errors or anything when it comes to this array.  Matter of fact, it works just the way that I need it to in the overall scheme of things.  Thanks for any and all help in understanding how and why this is the way it is.  Also attached screenshot for better visual aid.

[image: Confusing intellisense]

Comment: I know this isn't an answer to your quesiton, but since you're in .NET, why would you be using .ini files?  Using the App.Config (or web.config if it's an ASP.NET site) and exctracting values using System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager is ***SO much easier***, and it's "the .NET way" to do such things.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx

Comment: My program accesses an INI file created and used by a VB6 program.

Comment: Gotcha!  Valid case for using them.  No offense, I was just asking.

Comment: @DavidStratton: None taken.  Was just letting you know. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here :

```
RigInfo = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\\hddrigsite.ini");
```

You are assigning the variable with a new value.. In this case a new string[].

Comment: Accepted this as the answer.  Despite the fact that all 8 answers have essentially the same thing, this was the one that is at the top of the list as "oldest".

Answer (score 4):

Because you have changed the reference that is stored in your variable in this line:

```
RigInfo = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\\hddrigsite.ini");
```

Answer (score 3):

What you did is you over-wrote your 9-element array with a completely new array on

```
RigInfo = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\\hddrigsite.ini");
```

Answer (score 2):

the array is 'redefined' by the ReadAllLines call. if you had assigned each line to the array by index then you woudl get an error, but in this case, you redirected your pointer from the memory allocated to your array, and pointed it to the output of the ReadAllLines method.

always be weary of Arr = somthing, since that will alter the array reference itself.

Answer (score 1):

You assign `File.ReadAllLines` to it, so new memory will be allocated and the array is an entire new array. You basically overwrite your previous assignment.

Answer (score 1):

RigInfo contains more than the 9 elements expected because this line:

RigInfo = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\hddrigsite.ini");

discards the original RigInfo and creates a ***new*** string array with the results of File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\hddrigsite.ini")

Answer (score 0):

By `RigInfo = File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\\hddrigsite.ini");`, you are assigning a `new array` resulting from `File.ReadAllLines(fileLocation[1] + "\\hddrigsite.ini");` of size `30` to `RigInfo` variable.

If you do

```
  RigInfo [indx++] = one line at a time
```

then it will fail after 9th element as you are using the previously define array.

Comment: as much as the asker might be curious about that one too, he was asking about a different array

Comment: Actually, I wasn't at all confused about this particular array, but I can now see where it would follow the same concept.  However, I know that the fileLocation will only ever be 2 elements.

Comment: @SamIam I updated with RingInfo. Same logic goes with fileLocation varaible.

Comment: @TyrionLannister: Good, you got the concept(which holds true for fileLocation  variable as well) still I updated the answer with RingInfo.